# Why I can't install pyinstaller on my mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pyinstaller

I've been trying to install pyinstaller using `pip3 install pyinstaller` while having python 3.7 installed on my mac.

I get an error that says that the fitz module wasn't found. What is this fitz module? I have tried `pip3 install fitz` but it didn't work as well.

I have tried `pip install pyinstaller` it doesn't work.

Update: I also have the error `error building wheel`.

Comment: Have you tried to create virtualenv and install it on it?

Answer (score 0):

Download pyinstaller from [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases)
Then extract it and run the following command, you have to run this command with administrator privilage
    python setup.py install
    pyinstaller --version

Comment: I have this error when I try to do what you suggest. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Comment: which version of python that you are using?